# How to send debug text from C# class to ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, debugging, web

I am working on a C# class that is a part of my ASP.Net Web Site.

Is there a simple way to output some log/debugging text to the top of the page.  My class does NOT inherit from Page.  I want to display variable values, etc.

The class represents an Exam object that I use in some of my aspx pages.  The variables that I want to display are private and therefore inaccessible to my aspx pages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can just do this

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("your message goes here");
```

or write a helper method

```
public static void writeOut(string message) {
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(message);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anywhere in the context of an http request you can reach the current executing page as follows.

```
Page page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
```

You are free to cast to your own page type. So you can write debug info to labels, textboxes etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `Response.Write` method

```
var pathOfYourLog = "";
var log = File.ReadAllLines(pathOfYourLog);
YourHttpContext.Response.Write(log);
```

Comment: Thanks.  It looks like it should be HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(log)  This was very helpful.

Comment: Thank's Justin i'am happy to help you